# jQuery mobile highlight effect

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am looking to apply a jquery ui like highlight effect to an element , but I am using jquery mobile. Is there anything built into jquery mobile that would allow me to do that, without referencing any of the jquery ui stuff ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think jQM offers anything like this. BTW Is this what you're referencing to? http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight Could you go more into the specifics on what it is you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: yes that ( docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight ) is exactly what I am refering to ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work?

NOTE: this might affect the hash navigation but it's all CSS

- http://jsfiddle.net/MEzAU/

CSS

```
:target {
    -webkit-animation: target-fade 3s 1;
    -moz-animation: target-fade 3s 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes target-fade {
    0% { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1); }
    100% { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); }
}
@-moz-keyframes target-fade {
    0% { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1); }
    100% { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); }
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#3">Link 3</a>
<p id="1">Paragraph 1</p>
<p id="2">Paragraph 2</p>
<p id="3">Paragraph 3</p>
```

Link reference:

- http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/yellow-fade-technique-css-animations

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this yellow fade technique solution: http://jsfiddle.net/xb8Km/

Its a nice solution because you don't have to use :target, which is built for anchors hrefs that could interfere with jQuery Mobile ajax hrefs; it also doesn't need the .effect function from jQuery UI which is not designed for jQuery mobile.

```
<div class="yft">
    <div class="content">This is some content</div>
    <div class="yft_fade">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".yft").click(function() {
        $(this).find(".yft_fade").show().fadeOut();
    });
  });
</script>

<style>
  .yft_fade {
    background-color:yellow;
    display:none;
  }
  .content {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
  }
</style>
```

​

Comment: The code fades out a yellow div container which is positioned behind the text.